# update all fields of an entity in jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have tow entity User and Project that they have "one to many" relationship and I want to find the User then find the specific Project that belong to User and then update it, but I can't.
framework Struts2 + Hibernate .

```java
@Entity (name = "User")
@Table (name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable{
@Id
@Column (name = "user_id", columnDefinition = "number")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "gen")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "seq")
private int id;

@Basic
@Column(name = "user_name", columnDefinition = "nvarchar2(20)")
private String userName;

@Basic
@Column(name = "password", columnDefinition ="nvarchar2(20)")
private String password;

@Basic
@Column(name = "create_date",columnDefinition = "date")
private Date creation_date;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private List<Project> projectses;

public List<Project> getProjectses() {
    return projectses;
}

public void setProjectses(List<Project> projectses) {
    this.projectses = projectses;
}
```

and Project entity

```java
@Entity(name = "Project")
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project implements Serializable {
@Id
@Column(name = "project_id" , columnDefinition = "number")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "projectSeq", sequenceName = "projectGen")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,generator = "projectSeq")
private int projectId;

@Basic
@Column(name = "project_name" , columnDefinition = "nvarchar2(20)")
private String projectName;

@Basic
@Column(name = "project_description" , columnDefinition = nvarchar2(20)")
private String projectDescription;

@Basic
@Column(name = "start_date",columnDefinition = "date")
private Date startDate;

@Basic
@Column(name = "due_date",columnDefinition = "date")
private Date dueDate;

@Basic
@Column(name = "project_status",columnDefinition = "nvarchar2(20)")
private String projectStatus;

@Basic
@Column(name = "project_amount",columnDefinition = "number(8)")
private int projectAmount;
```

Comment: *but I can't* -- please elaborate, how you try to make it, what errors occur and so on

Comment: Shouldn join column be project_id?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou my update method has a parameter (User user) then User userProject= (User) entityManager.createQuery("select u from User u where u.id=:userId").setParameter("userId",user.getId()).getSingleResult();  userProject.setProject(user.getProject); entityManager.persist(userProject);  and error is value is too long for column

Comment: 1. Simplify your class for the question 2. put the code in comment back to the question itself 3. properly format your code  4. The error is IMPORTANT for people to understand the problem.  Extract the meaningful part out and post it here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three corrections come in mind, that may make your code behave well:

- Use [`EntityManager#find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-) instead of HQL to lookup entity by id;
- Use only one of `@Basic` or `@Column` (I'd prefer [`@Column`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Column.html)), there is no need to use both for a single element;
- If error is "*value is too long for column*", maybe it is time to check if some of `Project` elements are longer than 20 chars defined in `columnDefinition`?

Check length of string elements in `Project` entities, and if there are some longer than 20 characters, say, 500, modify `columnDefinition` for those elements, e. g.:

```
@Column(name = "project_description", columnDefinition = "nvarchar2(500)")
private String projectDescription;
```

I also suggest to drop tables after such modifications (to allow JPA create new according to new definitions) or manually modify their definitions in DB.

Answer (score 0):

```
User u = (User)entityManager.createQuery(SELECT u FROM User u JOIN FETCH u.Project where u.id = :id).setParameter("id",your_userId).uniqueResult();
```

Get The user object , you will get it with the set of projects associated with that user

update the data you want : -

```
List<Project> userProjects = u.getProjectses();   
for(int i = 0 ; i < userProjects.size() ; i++){
   Project p = userProjects.get(i);
   entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
   p.setProjectName("test"); 
   entityManager.merge(p); 
   entityManager.getTransaction().commit(); 
}
```